# Pagination of nested objects in angular js

Tags: angularjs, pagination

I am starting out with angular and I have a nested object which i would like to paginate. The items to be paginated are some of the 'attributes' in the given object. The queuelist object is nested with array within array. Any help would be appreciated.
The plunker link for non-paginated data is:

https://plnkr.co/edit/zgo0msd6y5ba6DJ6qGlc?p=preview

app.js:

```
var app = angular.module("myApp",[])
                 .controller("mycontroller",['$scope',function($scope){

  $scope.queuelist = [
  {
    "name": "ONE",
    "QueueList": [
      {
        "id": 1,
        "attributes": {
          "a": 1,
          "b": "2017-07-25T12:57:06Z",
          "c": 1500967626000,
          "d": "asdasd",
          "e": "aasdasdasd",
          "f": 0
        },
        "$$hashKey": "object:64"
      },
      {
        "id": 2,
        "attributes": {
          "a": 1,
          "b": "2017-07-25T12:57:06Z",
          "c": 1500967626000,
          "d": "asdasd",
          "e": "aasdasdasd",
          "f": 0
        },
        "$$hashKey": "object:65"
      },
      {
        "id": 3,
        "attributes": {
          "a": 1,
          "b": "2017-07-25T12:57:06Z",
          "c": 1500967626000,
          "d": "asdasd",
          "e": "aasdasdasd",
          "f": 0
        },
        "$$hashKey": "object:66"
      }
    ],
    "$$hashKey": "object:59"
  },
  {
    "name": "TWO",
    "QueueList": [
      {
        "id": 4,
        "attributes": {
          "a": 1,
          "b": "2017-07-25T12:57:06Z",
          "c": 1500967626000,
          "d": "asdasd",
          "e": "aasdasdasd",
          "f": 0
        },
        "$$hashKey": "object:72"
      },
      {
        "id": 5,
        "attributes": {
          "a": 1,
          "b": "2017-07-25T12:57:06Z",
          "c": 1500967626000,
          "d": "asdasd",
          "e": "aasdasdasd",
          "f": 0
        },
        "$$hashKey": "object:73"
      },
      {
        "id": 6,
        "attributes": {
          "a": 1,
          "b": "2017-07-25T12:57:06Z",
          "c": 1500967626000,
          "d": "asdasd",
          "e": "aasdasdasd",
          "f": 0
        },
        "$$hashKey": "object:74"
      },
      {
        "id": 7,
        "attributes": {
          "a": 1,
          "b": "2017-07-25T12:57:06Z",
          "c": 1500967626000,
          "d": "asdasd",
          "e": "aasdasdasd",
          "f": 0
        },
        "$$hashKey": "object:75"
      }
    ],
    "$$hashKey": "object:60"
  }
];


  $scope.objects = [];


   /*                  
  for(i=0;i<$scope.data.length;i++){
      $scope.data2.push($scope.data[i].QueueList);
  };
   */

    for(i=0;i<$scope.queuelist.length;i++){
      for(j=0;j<$scope.queuelist[i].QueueList.length;j++){
          $scope.objects.push($scope.queuelist[i].QueueList[j].attributes);
      };
    };              
   }])
```

and index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="myApp">
    <head>
        <script type= "text/javascript" src= "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.2/angular.js"></script>
        <script type= "text/javascript" src= "app.js"></script>
        <style>
            table, td, th {    
            border: 1px solid #ddd;
            text-align: left;
            }

            table {
            border-collapse: collapse;
            width: 100%;
            }

            th, td {
            padding: 15px;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div ng-controller="mycontroller">

            <div ng-repeat="queueJob in queuelist">
                {{queueJob.name}}
                <table>
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th><b>a</b></th>
                            <th><b>b</b></th>
                            <th><b>c</b></th>
                            <th><b>e</b></th>
                            <th><b>f</b></th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        <tr ng-repeat="queue in queueJob.QueueList">
                            <td>{{queue.attributes.a}}</td>
                            <td>{{queue.attributes.b}}</td>
                            <td>{{queue.attributes.c}}</td>
                            <td>{{queue.attributes.e}}</td>
                            <td>{{queue.attributes.f}}</td>
                        </tr>
                        <br/><br/>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
                <br/><br/>
                <br/><br/>
            </div>

        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I need separate pagination for each table. Thanks

Comment: All of your `attributes` objects in your sample data are exactly the same. Navigating next/previous between them will render the same display.... or is it the values within the `attributes` object that you want to navigate through (`a`, `b`, `c`, `d`, `e`, `f`)? A table/screenshot showing the expected display would be most helpful.

Comment: Hai matthew, i was too lazy to make up seperate datas. so i just edited the 'values' in each attribute. The 'keys' are identical in every case. Check out the new plunker with edited values.

Comment: check out http://ng-table.com/#/ ng-table directive , makes pagination and more stuff easily

Comment: @PanosK I tried that. couldnt get it to work unfortunately

Comment: @MatthewCawley sorry, What i want is, i want to paginate each row under a,b,c,d,e,f for both the tables. So if the count is 1 in table 1 for example only one row should be shown .I use the term 'both' loosely as the the number of elements may increase later.

Comment: @MatthewCawley The data itself is a dummy data with format similar to mine.

Comment: Something like this [CodePen Demo](https://codepen.io/mjcwly/pen/VMewgZ/)

Comment: @MatthewCawley Thanks!

Comment: @MatthewCawley Suppose i want to change the number of rows in each table for example lets say 5 such that the number of pages become 1, how do i go about it? thanks in advance.

Comment: @krishnair1123 I've updated the code pen demo. Basically you need to create a `$scope.pageSize` variable and then change your `ng-repeat` so that you pass `queueJob.pageIndex*pageSize` to the `startFrom` filter, and pass the `$scope.pageSize` variable to the `limitTo` filter. I also tweaked the `$scope.isLast()` function slightly to take into account a variable page size.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this using a combination of:

- A custom filter (to determine how many records to skip), and...
- The built in [**limitTo**](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/limitTo) filter (to limit the number of records to the desired page size)

**1) First create the custom filter.**

```
app.filter("startFrom", function thisFilter() {
  return function(input, index) {
    return input.slice(parseInt(index));
  };
});
```

The filter takes in an `index` which it goes on to use in the [**Array.prototype.slice()**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) method. The `slice()` method slices the array at the given index and returns a new array containing all remaining objects. The filter returns the new array.

**2) Use the custom filter and built-in limitTo filter in the `ng-repeat` directive.**

```
<tr ng-repeat="queue in queueJob.QueueList | startFrom: queueJob.pageIndex | limitTo: 1">
```

Here we use the newly created `startFrom` custom filter passing it the `queueJob.pageIndex` property as the filter's `index` parameter. We pass the results of the `startFrom` filter onto the `limitTo` filter which reduces the number of records to `1`.

**Note**: We have to use the `pageIndex` property on the `queueJob` itteration variable because this `ng-repeat` is contained within another `ng-repeat` and so a `$scope.pageIndex` variable would have been conflicted and subsequently overwritten.

**3) Create next and previous buttons**

```
<tr>
  <td colspan="5">
    <button class="btn" 
      ng-click="onPrevClicked(queueJob)"
      ng-disabled="isFirst(queueJob)">
      <span class="fa fa-chevron-left"></span>
      Prev
    </button>
    <button class="btn" 
      ng-click="onNextClicked(queueJob)"
      ng-disabled="isLast(queueJob)">
      Next
      <span class="fa fa-chevron-right"></span>
    </button>
    Page {{ queueJob.pageIndex + 1 }}
  </td>
</tr>
```

Here we use `ng-click` directives to invoke controller functions that increment/decrement the `queueJob` object's `pageIndex` property. We also use `ng-disabled` directives to prevent navigating next/previous if the user is on the first/last record.

**4) Create the bindable functions in the controller**

```
$scope.onPrevClicked = onPrevClicked;
$scope.onNextClicked = onNextClicked;
$scope.isFirst = isFirst;
$scope.isLast = isLast;

function onPrevClicked(obj) {
  if (!isFirst(obj)) obj.pageIndex--;
}

function onNextClicked(obj) {
  if (!isLast(obj)) obj.pageIndex++;
}

function isFirst(obj) {
  return obj.pageIndex === 0;
}

function isLast(obj) {
  return obj.pageIndex + 1 === obj.QueueList.length;
}
```

**5) Initialise the `pageIndex` properties upfront**

```
$scope.queuelist.forEach(function(obj) {
  obj.pageIndex = 0;
});
```

This initialised the `pageIndex` as a number that can be incremented and subsequently decremented.

**Demo**

[**CodePen: Using a custom filter to do pagination**](https://codepen.io/mjcwly/pen/VMewgZ)