# Pagination on nested lists in Angular2

Tags: angular, pagination, nested-loops, ngfor

I have a nested list of items that I'm trying to paginate, but most implementations of Pagination I can find don't appear to work on nested lists.

app.component.html:

```
<div *ngFor="let department of myJSON">
    <h2>{{department.title}}</h2>
    <p>{{department.description}}</p>
    <ul class="list">
        <li *ngFor="let person of department.list">
            {{person.name}}
            {{person.phone}}
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

To clarify, I need only **one** pagination element on this page, and it used by all departments, to paginate every 10 "li" elements. If a **department** is empty (Because it has zero elements on the currently displayed page), then it will receive **display:none**.

I've tried NgxPaginationModule, but it doesn't appear to have any support for recognizing elements outside of the current **ngFor**.

The closest thing I've found is this:  [Pagination of nested objects in angular js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46274943/pagination-of-nested-objects-in-angular-js), wherein he explains how to write a custom Pager from **scratch**, but again, there doesn't appear to be any way to count how many LIs are displayed, and only display 10 per page.

Any help or direction would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the end, I **couldn't** find any solutions that didn't force me to build a complete pagination from scratch.

Therefore, I instead flattened and rebuilt my arrays, and re-wrote **app.component.html** in order to **remove all nested loops**, and used standard ngx-pagination.

Here is the final version of the HTML I used:

app.component.html:

```
//itemList = current page of items.
//i = index
//person = item on page
//If a person is the first one on the page(index=0) or his department ID
//is different from the previous person's department ID, then print 
//the .deparment-section block.

<ng-template ngFor let-person let-i="index" let-itemList="ngForOf" [ngForOf]="personList | paginate: { itemsPerPage: 10, currentPage: p }">
    <div class="department-section" *ngIf="  person.department.id && (i == 0 || person.department.id != itemList[i-1].department.id)">
        <h2>{{departmentList[person.department.id].name}}</h2>
        <p>{{departmentList[person.department.id].description}}</p>                
    </div>
    <div class="person">
        {{person.name}}
        {{person.phone}}
    </div>
</ng-template>
```

Comment: You had the exact same problem that I am currently having (except with AngularJS).  Thanks for actually following up and saying what you ended up doing!  I may have to go the route of just flattening my data too, would just be a huge refactor.

Answer (score 1):

Eliezer, the "key" is add to yours department the variables "count" and "activePage". You can use a map some like

```
//supouse you have a an array "departments" that is 
//an object with title,description and list -this last is an array too
this.department=department.map(d=>{
   title:d.title,
   description:d.description,
   count:d.list.length,
   activePage:0,
   list:d.list
});
```

then you can use split to show only the ten persons

```
<div *ngFor="let department of myJSON">
    <h2>{{department.title}}</h2>
    <p>{{department.description}}</p>
    <ul class="list">
        <li *ngFor="let person of 
                department.list.slice(department.activePage,10*(department.activePage))">
            {{person.name}}
            {{person.phone}}
        </li>
    </ul>
    <button (click)="department.activePage++">more</button>
    <button (click)="department.activePage--">less</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply, Eliseo, but the code here will display 10 <li>s per department, **which is not what I need at all**. Most pagination components can do that..

My desired result is to display 10 <li>s per page, but if the <li>s are inside a category, then group them together by department.

Comment: Then I'm afraid you must work with the array to create an array of pages[], each with the elements you want show. This elements should have type,title,description,personName,personPhone (type sirve to show or title and description or personName and personPhone). then your *ngFor="let data of pages[paginaActual]"

Comment: That doesn't solve *anything*. It just pushes to all the work to **App.component.ts** instead of **App.component.html**.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this issue, by creating a new component. In that way, it was easier to implement the frontend pagination and it minimized the nested NgFor.

Here's the sample code on what I'm trying to say:

**Parent component:**

```html
<div *ngFor="let res of result">
    <p>{{res.name}}</p>
</div>

<app-child [holder]="res"></app-child>
```

**Child component**

```html
<div *ngFor = "let res1 of holder">
    <p>{{res1.middleName}}</p>
</div>
```

**Note: Apply the pagination logic in your child component.**